# Events of a non-delegate type

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I've implemented a class that looks like this interface:

```
[ImmutableObject(true)]
public interface ICustomEvent
{
    void Invoke(object sender, EventArgs e);

    ICustomEvent Combine(EventHandler handler);
    ICustomEvent Remove(EventHandler handler);

    ICustomEvent Combine(ICustomEvent other);
    ICustomEvent Remove(ICustomEvent other);
}
```

This CustomEvent class works much like a MulticastDelegate. It can invoked. It can be combined with another CustomEvent. And a CustomEvent can be removed from another CustomEvent.

Now, I want to declare a class like this:

```
class EventProvider
{
    public event CustomEvent MyEvent;

    private void OnMyEvent()
    {
        var myEvent = this.MyEvent;
        if (myEvent != null) myEvent.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not compile. A Compiler Error CS0066 appears:

*'EventProvider.MyEvent': event must be of a delegate type*

Basically, what I need is a property that has **add** and **remove** accessors instead of **get** and **set**. I think the only way to have that is using the **event** keyword. I know that one obvious alternative is to declare two methods that would do the adding and removing, but I want to avoid that too.

Does anybody knows if there is a nice solution this problem? I wonder if there is any way to cheat the compiler to accept a non-delegate type as an event. A custom attribute, perhaps.

By the way, someone asked a similar question in experts-exchange.com. Since that site is not free, I can't see the responses. Here is the topic: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21697455.html

Comment: From the name of his event in the EE link, it sounds like he's trying to do COM events. You should avoid this.

Comment: I don't really see the problem. What's wrong with regular events?

Comment: There is no problem with regular events.
The problem is with regular delegates. They keep strong references to the target object. I implemented a class that works like a delegate, but uses a WeakReference internally. If I only could use it in an event property, the solution would be perfect.
And that's only one of the possibilities. I know that it may sound like reinventing the wheel, but I'm quite sure it isn't.

Comment: If you're going to use your own event-style architecture, I would recommend patterning it after `IObservable` rather than the delegate combine/remove pattern.  The latter creates unavoidable ambiguities if an events get subscribed/unsubscribed more than once, requires an event subscriber to keep a strong reference to the publisher to allow for unsubscription, even in cases where no strong reference would otherwise be required, makes it hard to keep a list of necessary unsubscriptions, etc.  The former avoids all those problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to add and remove `CustomEvent` objects from the event (instead of regular delegates), there are two options:

Make an implicit cast from ICustomEvent to EventHandler (or some other delegate) that returns an instance method of ICustomEvent (probably Invoke), then use the Target property of the delegate to get the original ICustomEvent in the `add` and `remove` accessors.

**EDIT**: Like this:

```
CustomEvent myEvent;
public event EventHandler MyEvent {
    add {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        var customHandler = value.Target as ICustomEvent;

        if (customHandler != null)
            myEvent = myEvent.Combine(customHandler);
        else
            myEvent = myEvent.Combine(value);   //An ordinary delegate
    }
    remove {
        //Similar code
    }
}
```

Note that you'll still need to figure out how to add the first handler if it's a delegate (if the `myEvent` field is `null`)

---

Make a writable property of type CustomEvent, then overload the `+` and `-` operators to allow `+=` and `-=` on the property.

**EDIT**: To prevent your callers from overwriting the event, you could expose the previous value in CustomEvent (I'm assuming it works like an [immutable stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack.aspx)) and, in the setter, add

```
if (myEvent.Previous != value && value.Previous != myEvent)
    throw new ArgumentException("You cannot reset a CustomEvent", "value");
```

Note that when the last handler is removed, both `value` and `myEvent.Previous` will be `null`.

Comment: About the implicit cast option: it's an interesting idea. I see that it's possible to hide a CustomEvent inside a delegate. Maybe, I could mark the method with a custom attribute in order to differentiate a CustomEvent from a Delegate. I'll try to code it. thanks!

Comment: About the writable property option: I have considered it in the past, but I dislike it for one good reason. Any external code would be able to overwrite the current CustomEvent. I want a solution that provides the same pattern that regular events do: user code is only able to add/remove the handlers it knows. Invoking the event and reading the current handlers should not be allowed.

Comment: @1st: What would be the point of a custom attribute?  I don't see what you're saying there.

Comment: You need to view Google's cache of the page.  Search Google for cache:_<any ExpertsExchange Url>_, or use Google Toolbar's view cache button

Comment: @1st: A nice-to-have feature is being able to implicitly convert a EventHandler to a CustomEvent. Using a delegate typed event, I could have the 2 options. The added value could be either an common EventHandler or a CustomEvent disguised as an EventHandler. To distinguish between the two, I could check if the delegate Method has some custom attribute. I'm starting to liek this solution.

Comment: @2nd: Indeed, this can work too. Now, I don't know what option to pursue first. I guess I'll be forced to accept your answer. :)

Comment: @1st: You don't need to check for an attribute - you can simply check whether the Target property is an instance of ICustomEvent, like this: `if (value.Target is ICustomEvent)`

Comment: @1st: You're right, I don't need attributes. I'll just ask one correction. A null value is acceptable, but has to be ignored. That's how regular events work. So, if you substitute the *throw new ArgumentNullException("value");* for a *return;* I accept your answer. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
CustomEvent myEvent

public event EventHandler MyEvent {
    add { myEvent = myEvent.Combine(value); }
    remove {myEvent = myEvent.Remove(value); }
}
```

You can add and remove normal EventHandler delegates to it, and it will execute the `add` and `remove` accessors.

---

**EDIT**: You can find a weak event implementation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WeakEvents.aspx).
**2<sup>nd</sup> EDIT**: Or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx).

Comment: 1st) Thanks for your suggestion, but it's 100% exactly to a regular event. That's not what I'm looking for;
2nd) I want to raise the event from the EventProvider class. I don't think raising events from external classes is a good idea in any situation;
3rd) Thanks for your links, but I already knew both of them. My code, by the way, is strongly inspired by the codeproject article you mentioned.

Comment: If the first one isn't what you want to do, what do you want?  <br>To be able to add `ICustomEvent`s?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your answer. You're right, I want to be able to add and remove ICustomEvent, not only EventHandler's. I fixed the question to make it clearer. (I would vote this answer up if I had enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish that you can't use delegates/events for?

This screams [Reinventing the Square Wheel (bottom of the page)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel), but that could just as well be me not understanding the problem.

Comment: I would tend to agree. If you need to perform tasks on the adding and removing of event handlers, use the `add` and `remove` accessors, which you mention.

Comment: One of the possibilities is a easier way to implement a transparent Weak Event Pattern.

Comment: Perhaps, but then you have code that violates everything you already know about [.NET events and weak events][1], which devastates code readability even though you're *trying* to improve it.

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use the "+=" and the "-=" operators on your CustomEvent class?
You cannot override the "+=" and the "-=" operators directly, but they are evaluated by "+" and "-" operator.

*Assignment operators cannot be overloaded, but +=, for example, is evaluated using +, which can be overloaded.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(VS.90).aspx

So instead of having event-like add and remove methods, you can have a field or a property that can be combined by += and -= operators. Besides it encapsulates the combination logic inside your own CustomEvent class.

Carlos Loth.

Comment: That's the same as the second option that SLaks proposed above. He also proposed a special treatment to avoid the possibility of overwriting the event. To be honest, I prefer his first option. I have already coded it and I'm doing some tests.

Comment: I have to agree with you, the first option is better because you acctualy can use "regular" event handlers in addition to your custom weak event. 
Besides, I haven't noticed his comment about overloading the + and - operators. Sorry.