# C# adding objects (similar to delegates)

Tags: c#, object, delegates

I want to ask, can you do something similar to this?

```
Event += eventInstance;
```

Event is a class

I want to do something similar to delegates:

```
Write write1 = new Write(() => Console.WriteLine("Write1"));
Write write2 = new Write(() => Console.WriteLine("Write2"));
Write write3 = new Write(() => Console.WriteLine("Write3"));

Write write = write1 + write2 + write3;
write();
```

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1134206/34397

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overload the [+ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324.aspx) and combine the delegates. Something like this:

```
public class Write
{
    private readonly Action _act;

    public Write(Action act)
    {
        _act = act;
    }

    public void Invoke()
    {
        _act();
    }

    public static Write operator +(Write left, Write right)
    {
        //Do appropriate null-checking.
        var del = (Action)Delegate.Combine(left._act, right._act);
        return new Write(del);
    }
}
```

And using it like so:

```
Write write1 = new Write(() => Console.WriteLine("Write1"));
Write write2 = new Write(() => Console.WriteLine("Write2"));
Write write3 = new Write(() => Console.WriteLine("Write3"));

Write writeall = write1 + write2 + write3;
writeall.Invoke();
```

Will print

```
Write1
Write2
Write3
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for your class.

```
class Write
{
    public static Write operator +(Write w1, Write w2)
    {
        // implementation, must return Write object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
Just create an `operator +`.

Your class should be immutable, and you'll probably want to use a flattened list of members.